# Русский язык в C++ (VSCode)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Я программирую на с++  в VSCode. Но я столкнулся с проблемой: у меня вместо русских символов выдаются “инопланетные иероглифы”. Использую последнюю версию VSCode. Компилятор: MinGW. “set locale” не работает. Желательное решение с помощью параметров или расширения. Чтобы распространялось на все файлы (c++).

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ваш ответ. Где конкретно у Вас возникает такая проблема? В коде (к примеру, комментарии), в самой IDE, в интегрированном терминале или мб при локализации вашего приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
...
}
```

Должно работать как на С, так и на С++.

Навряд ли можно на все файлы распространить через настройки, только отдельно для каждой программы, и то с помощью кода

Answer (score 0):

Просто пропиши setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

Должно работать:)

Comment: Он же сказал, что данный метод у него как раз и не работает